# simple jQuery Chaining insight

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought I understood the chaining power of jQuery, but now I'm a little confused.

Using the example of fading out a DIV, and then removing it:

- By jQuery chaining logic, I should be able to do:

  ```
  $(this).parent().fadeOut(500).remove();
  ```

But instead I have to do this:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(500,function() { $(this).remove(); });
```

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't call `.remove()` right away because the `.fadeOut()` operation is an asynchronous operation that returns right away (after it just starts the animation), but continues executing via timers.  When the `.fadeOut()` returns and the next chained operation executes, the animation has only just started - it has not completed.  If you do the `.remove()` with normal chaining, you remove it right away before the animation makes any progress.

So, as you have discovered, you have to wait until the completion callback is called for the animation and then you can remove it.

The one exception to this is additional chained animation calls.  You can chain animations because animations are a special case that go into the animation queue.  Once an animation has started, subsequent animation calls see that there's already an animation in progress and they go into an internal queue.  When the first animation finishes, it checks the animation queue to see if there are more chained animations to start.

Nearly all asynchronous operations in javascript are non-blocking like this.  That means that the call to start them is just that - a call to start them.  That call then returns right away and the rest of the operation proceeds via timers or other events and subsequent javascript continues executing (including other chained methods).  You will only know when the operation is actually done by registering for the completion callback.

The same is true for ajax operations, loading of images, etc...

You got me thinking about how to make the `.remove()` method work through the animation queue.   One can in fact do that by creating a new version of remove() like this:

```
$.fn.fxRemove = function() {
    this.queue(function(next) {
        $(this).remove();
        next();
    });
    return(this);
}
```

This form of remove goes in the animation queue and will execute when the animations chained before it are done.  So, you could then use:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(500).fxRemove();
```

There's a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/3Hg6G/

Comment: Just to add to that slightly.  Animations are added to a queue, non-animations are not.  `remove` is not an animation so it happens immediately.  Sticking something like `fadeIn` after the `fadeOut` would wait for `fadeOut` to complete, because it gets queued.  This is often misunderstood.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this design decition in jQuery. Doesn't it fool most beginners (if not all)?

Comment: @Leo - it's not really a design decision in jQuery.  Because of the way javascript works, operations that execute over a long period of time with the browser able to respond to events have to be asynchronous like this (e.g. non-blocking).  When they are asynchronous, the javascript engine will just execute the next chained operations.  There really isn't another way to use chaining and solve this problem unless jQuery somehow put all chained operations into a queue and that might end up being even more complicated.  Yes, it does fool beginners.  It is just something that has to be learned.

Comment: @JamesMontagne - we were thinking alike.  I have added a bit about the animation queue before I saw your comment.

Comment: I added an example of an `.fxRemove()` jQuery plug-in method that will let you chain the `remove()`.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thanks, I understand they have to be asynch, but I do not understand how that mixes with the syntax.

Comment: @Leo - difficult to explain in a comment.  The Javascript engine executes the chained methods one after another.  It doesn't know if they are synch or asynch.  Since an asynch method returns right away, all the subsequent methods get run before the asynch ones are finished with their asynch operation.

Comment: @jfriend00: hmm haven't reloaded this page since I posted, very similar answers

Comment: @jfriend00: I think I am beginning to understand. I thought the JavaScript engine could somehow get a chance to translate the code before it is executed but you are as far as I understand suggesting that it could not get that. I do not understand the limitations and possibilities there. I will just keep it that way for now.

Comment: This clearly explained the jQuery logic, thanks. The examples definitely helped also.

Comment: Thanks a lot for those explanations, very clear ! That helped me a lot to understand problems I've been having with my jquery chaining syntax, and why I had to use the fadeOut() callback for things to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin to make it wait for you.

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ntf6G/)

```
$.fn.q = function(fn) {
    var that = this, arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

    return this.queue(function(next) {
        that[fn].apply(that, arg);
        next(); 
    });
};
```

usage:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut(500).q('remove');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try it the way:

```
$(this).parent().fadeOut().delay(500).remove();
```

Comment: That will not work either.  The `.delay()` is not synchronous.  It is also asychronous (goes through the animation queue) just like the `.fadeOut()` so it won't delay when `.remove()` is actually called.

Comment: I think you'll find that this doesn't help at all because [the `.delay()` method](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) only delays subsequent animation methods.